# MySQL query not returning newly inserted record

Tags: php, mysql, innodb

We're seeing this behavior randomly on newly inserted records and only on the production database (Amazon's RDS). Looks like something related to a deadlock... (no errors reported)

The affected tables are InnoDB, payment_id is auto-increment and all transaction end-times are in the order of milliseconds. All the connections are on the same server, autocommit is enabled and there is no replication (as far as Amazon's documentation).

Connection #1:

> 2011-03-07 14:09:54 INSERT INTO payments SET payment_transaction = 'XYZ'

Connection #2:

> 2011-03-07 14:10:06: SELECT * FROM payments WHERE `payment_transaction` = 'XYZ' LIMIT 0, 1

Response: empty

> 2011-03-07 14:10:06: SELECT * FROM payments ORDER BY `payment_id` DESC LIMIT 0, 1

Response: [payment_id] => 26242, [payment_transaction] => ABC

> 2011-03-07 14:50:06: SELECT * FROM payments WHERE `payment_transaction` = 'XYZ' LIMIT 0, 1

Response: [payment_id] => 26243, [payment_transaction] => XYZ

Comment: What were you expecting would happen?

Comment: Is the data base using replication? Are the connections to the same server?

Comment: The (single) DB is running on Amazon's RDS and, according to their documentation, there is no replication involved.

Comment: The second query and the last query (same) should return the same result.

Comment: Check for whitespace when you entered it in, that could be the difference

Comment: Connection2 is made before making insert on connection1 ? and  whats is autocommit value, you can check it using "SELECT @@autocommit;"

Comment: You would get such behavior within a transaction due to MVCC. Have you confirmed that auto commit is on and each connection is not taken as a single transaction?

Comment: what is your transaction isolation level? might have something to do with that: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html

Comment: connection2 is being made, at least, 10 seconds after connection1; and autocommit is enabled (tested on command line and within the application itself).

Comment: The transaction isolation level is set to the default 'REPEATABLE-READ'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding some debug points to the application I noted that these (randomly problematic) INSERTs are actually taking around 50+ seconds to complete (in contrast to what the log was saying). So to anyone having this issue, make sure you benchmark the start and end times of the INSERT within your application environment.

Answer (score 0):

Its depend in what function you are using if undertand you, to see how many row effected by SELECT instruction use **mysql_num_rows()**, use **mysql_affected_rows()** with DELETE, UPDATE qnd INSERT instructions according to [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).